# Rails API app: (No MethodError) when I run foreman start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, foreman

I just created a new Rails API app and Im trying to run it first time.
I have the foreman gem installed and Im using the command

```
  foreman start
```

to start the server but Im getting these errors:

```
 Exiting
 21:52:55 web.1  |
 /Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/app1229/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb:8:in 
 `block in <top (required)>':
 undefined method `wrap_parameters' for ActionController::API:Class (NoMethodError)
 21:52:55 web.1  |  
 from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-gemset/gems/activesupport-
 3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
 21:52:55 web.1  |  
 from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-gemset/gems/activesupport- 
 3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
 21:52:55 web.1  |  
 from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-gemset/gems/activesupport-
 3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_lo
  ..........
```

Ive tried updating the gemset and restrating the terminal etc.

However nothing is working. Wondering if someone can give an idea as to how to proceed in the diagnosis of the source of this error

Thanks

---

EDIT
Here are the contents of the ApplicationController.rb

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::API 
   include ActionController::MimeResponds 
   include ActionController::ImplicitRender 

 end
```

gemfile:

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'
 gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
 gem 'rails-api'
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'thin'
 gem 'foreman'
 gem 'rabl'
 gem "paperclip"
 gem 'aws-sdk'
 group :development do
gem 'annotate', :git=>'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
gem 'debugger'
 end
```

Error points to line 8 in this file: wrap_parameters.rb

```
 # Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
 #
 # This file contains settings for ActionController::ParamsWrapper which
 # is enabled by default.

 # Enable parameter wrapping for JSON. You can disable this by setting :format to an    
   empty array.
 ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
   ERROR >>>>  wrap_parameters format: [:json]
 end

 # Disable root element in JSON by default.
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  self.include_root_in_json = false
 end
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `ActionController::API` is inheriting from `ActionController::Base`?

Comment: This are the contents of my application.rb file: 
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::Helpers
  include ActionController::Cookies
  
end

Does this help? Clarify?

Comment: Is the output the same if you just `rails server` instead of `foreman start`?

Comment: Yes:
ruby-1.9.3-p194 AM@~/Documents/RailsWS/app1229 >rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/app1229/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `wrap_parameters' for ActionController::API:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: This might have something to do with the gemset, but Im not sure what

Comment: So I commented out this ERROR producing line :ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  #wrap_parameters format: [:json]
end

And the server boots up fine. Is it safe to do this?

Answer (score 8):

The problem in the wrap_parameters is fixed in version 0.0.3 of rails-api, but for previously generated applications we have to substitute the first block of code in initializers/wrap_parameters.rb for this one:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  include ActionController::ParamsWrapper
  wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
end
```

I've tested it right now in one of my heroku apps and works perfectly. No need to rewrite the code in full featured rails anymore :)

Comment: This was so perfect that I just had to say thanks even though it's been a while since you answered this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `Procfile` in the root of your Rails project directory? For the most simple setup my Procfiles usually look like this:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
```

(Of course you'd need `gem 'thin'` in your Gemfile as well.)

Comment: These are the contents of my PROC file when I get the error:

"web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV" I also have the thin gem installed

Comment: Try substituting for the configuration I have above and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Unfortunately, still getting the same error. Could this have anything to do with my gemset?

Comment: Try eliminating each one of the included modules in your ApplicationController, one at a time, until you no longer get the error. I suspect one of those modules is interfering.

Comment: Hmm. doesnt seem to work. For some reason, so frustrating. Im not sure what to do :(

Comment: You'll want to post the contents of your ApplicationController as well as your Gemfile to your question so we can get to the bottom of this.